# Vector specialization for scalar types gone in Visual C++ 2015?

Tags: vector, visual-studio-2015, msvcrt

While upgrading our project to Visual Studio 2015 we met an issue with destruction of large `vector<unsigned char>`, which was storing an image - about 5 Mb. In Debug builds it took about 0.5 second, while for char (a `POD` type) this should be - in principle - only one memory deallocation call.

The debugger showed that the implementation in VS 2015 (VC 14.0) iterates through each element in the destructed array and calls its destructor - no matter if it's a `POD` type or a complex type. So I understand the problem and why it is only occuring in Debug builds - in Release build the compiler is clever enough to remove unnecessarry calls of empty functions.

Actually there was a specialization for scalar types in all previous versions of Visual Studio (checked 2003 and 2012):

```
template<class _Alloc> inline
void _Destroy_range(typename _Alloc::pointer _First,
    typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al,
    _Scalar_ptr_iterator_tag)
{   // destroy [_First, _Last), scalar type (do nothing)
}
```

but now it's gone and all we have is

```
template<class _Alloc> inline
void _Destroy_range(typename _Alloc::pointer _First,
    typename _Alloc::pointer _Last, _Alloc& _Al)
{   // destroy [_First, _Last)
for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
    _Al.destroy(_STD addressof(*_First));
}
```

I just can't understand why this useful and easy optimization was removed. And I couldn't found any comments on this from Microsoft.

**The questions**:

- Does anybody know the reason for this change?
- Is there a way to fix slow destruction issue without changing each POD vector in our code (to custom container or `unique_ptr<type[]>` / `boost::scoped_array`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theory seems to be correct, they recently removed the specialization and it looks like a bug. A dev on the team says that the change was made because there were some constructors that weren't being called that should be called. This new version is probably more technically correct but has terrible perf implications for Debug.

See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2661660/missing-vector-specialization-for-scalar-types

I'm hitting this problem too. Here's my test program:

```
int main()
{
    auto foo = new std::vector<unsigned char>(100 * 1000 * 1000);
    delete foo;
    return 0;
}
```

This runs in ~54ms in VS 2015 w/ toolset=vc120, while it takes ~11,000ms w/ toolset=vc140. All the time is spent on the delete line.

I haven't found a workaround yet.

Comment: Great, thanks for the finding! I hope they indeed fix this in next update. For my needs (creating buffers for C interaction) I switched to using `unique_ptr<type[]>` and works fine for this easy job.

Comment: Looks to be fixed in VS 2015 Update 3. From the release notes:

_We've restored debug mode performance when destroying ranges of trivial objects that regressed in Update 2, like in vector._

Comment: I just confirmed that it's indeed fixed in Update 3.